# How to make botton change direction after some time flutter

Tags: flutter, time

I have to set 2 different direction for one botton amd this direction have to change in function of time. So when you first open the route, the botton lead to one route amd after some seconds the same botton lead to another route.

Answer (score 0):

You can see example below to see how to do this.

```
import 'dart:async';
/// After 10 second
final timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
  /// change the sound to play
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you also tell me how and where write sounds to play in this case ?

Comment: I mean how to set the sounds name (asset, so local file)?

Comment: ```
import 'dart:async';
/// After 10 second
bool playFirstSound = true;
final timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
  /// change the sound to play
  setState(() {
    playFirstSound = false;
  });
});


ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Play Sound"),
  onPressed: () {
    if (playFirstSound) {
        // play first sound
    } else {
    //    play second sound
    }
  }
)
```

https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio
check here for plugin to use to play sounds.

Comment: Is this method usefull to change the audio that a button plays or it's just to play sounds in general?

Comment: that a button changes

Comment: https://gist.github.com/toykam/a1b5b86880898ce77614b80254a4248a
for better view of the code, check here

Comment: I'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge. Can you tell me how to yse it with a button?

Comment: I have add an elevated button in the code, you use that.

Comment: I need to change the direction of the button, I need the same button to play different sounds

Comment: yeah, the playing of sound will happen on the oppressed function, and that is where you will check if the time has passed or not.

Comment: I'm not explaining well. I don't need a changment of direction after I press the button. I need that changement after some time. So no one press the button and the direction changes.

Comment: I know, and that is what the timer wants to do for you, from what is in the code, after 10sec, playFirstSound variable will change to false, then on click of the button, a decision will be made based on this variable.

Comment: if the playFirstSound variable is true, then, the first sound will be played, else the second sound.

Comment: Hi, again. How can I use this for more than two audios and not in a periodica way?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by non periodical way, and will the sound to be played be selected at random from a list of sounds, or it is just going to follow the sequence in the list of sound, lastly, is the list of sound fixed?

Comment: Yes I mean sounds have to be played following a sequenze, not random, and with no periodical I mean that in the end of the sequence the botton don't have to lead user to the first sound again but just end with the last sound set. Also I need to choose  between each changement of direction of the button a different timer so not a general timer for all of them. I don't know what do you mean with fixed

Comment: Always I mean have to follo a sequence under button direction not be played automatically affer some amount of time, user have always to press the butto to play sounds and if user do not play sound the app go to the end of this sequence with out play any sound but changing direction under the button that in the end become the direction tk the last sound of the sequencre, I hope to have been creare

Comment: Or if the user press button once the app will play just the sound that was connected to the button in that instant of time

Comment: Can you just describe  what you are trying to achieve. I think that will give more meaning to this.

Comment: I'm trying to make a sort of music player. When user open the app, he will find just one button. If he presses the button in the first 15 seconds he will play song 1, if he wait those 15 seconds and then press the button within other 20 seconds, he will play song 2. If he don't press the button in this 20 seconds either and he press the button after those 20 seconds he will play song 3. And so on with other songs. If user don't press the button, Notting happens. He will have to restart app o press another botton to go back and restart

Comment: Hmm, but if it is a music player, I should be able to play which ever music I want....

Comment: Yes yes but I want to make something different, do you have some idea on what kind of code i can use?

Comment: okay, can you make me understand what you want to do exactly, not the logic you want to do?

Comment: First of all thank you so much for spending your time

Comment: I think there are some ways to achieve that, but I have no idea how to write the code of them. Examples: 
1. changing the file path of the asset audio, to play with the button, with a variable (starting with assets/audios/song1.mp3 and after some seconds this path change in assets/audios/song2.mp3 and so on) 
2. Set a variable : play=0 ; timer 20s ; play=1 ; timer 50s; play=2; timer 70s play=3. Then create the button witch is an audio player and write if play=0 (ass../au../song1) ; if play=1 (ass../au../song2) and so on.

Comment: So i Taught at this two different examples

Comment: They are not two steps of the same way but 1. 2. Different ways

Comment: Any idea how to write it?